# Cherrypy and multiprocessesing/threading

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, cherrypy, multiprocess

I have created a webservice with `cherrypy`, where I use some different files as input. I would like to reload these files once in a while (e.g. every hour) and still get an answer while the files are reloaded. I expect I should use multiprocessing or threading, but I can't really figure out how to.

The class look like this.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

some_file=pd.read_csv("file_name.csv")
now=datetime.now()

class ClassName(object):    
    def __init__(self,input):
        self.input=input

    def method_name(self):
        return str(some_file.iloc[0,0])+"-"+str(now)+". "+str(self.input)
```

and the webservice

```
from FileNameOfClassAbove import ClassName
import cherrypy

class WebService(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        input=cherrypy.request.body.read()
        input=input.decode('utf-8')
        C=ClassName(input)
        out=C.method_name()
        return out

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = {'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0'}
    cherrypy.config.update(config)
    cherrypy.quickstart(WebService())
```

How do I reload `some_file` and `now` every hour? Moreover, I expect it would be better practice to avoid the global variables?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by reloading. But have you tried cron jobs to schedule repeated tasks? Is that what you are looking fot?

Comment: I would like to reload the file (`some_file`), since the file changes once in a while, without stopping the webservice.

Comment: Why reload. You can adjust file reading pointer you can read more about it. like file.seek(0) takes you at start of the file.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to read the file every time the webservice is called, since it is not performant enough. I only want to read the file every hour, to make sure that the variable is updated.

Comment: Can you just close the file and open it again programmatically ?

Comment: Yes, I just need to rerun this line `some_file=pd.read_csv("file_name.csv")`. But how do I do that once in a hour, while the webservice is still running without closing the webservice?

Comment: You can check cron jobs to do this hourly. Plus check how to close and open file using python that should address this.